# How to disable selection some item in a listview windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, listboxitem

I want to **disable selection** of some items in **listBoxEmployee** whole **isEnable** property = false but all of them still selectable and I dont know why. In my mainpage, my code is:

```
public SelectLevel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            passedLevel = (int)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["passedLevel"];

            List<LevelList> myData = new List<LevelList>();

            for (int i = 0; i <= passedLevel; i++)
            {
                myData.Add(new LevelList { levelNumber = i, urlImg = "Images/passed.png", IsEnabled = true});
            }

            for (int j = passedLevel + 1; j <= allLevel; j++)
            {
                myData.Add(new LevelList { levelNumber = j, urlImg = "Images/notpassed.png", IsEnabled = false });

            }

            listBoxEmployee.ItemsSource = myData;

        }
```

And my xaml page:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Grid Width="80" Height="80" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsEnabled}">
                                <Image Source="{Binding urlImg}" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsEnabled}"></Image>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsEnabled}" IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsEnabled}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="36" Foreground="Black" />

                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're really doing is setting the `IsHitTestVisible` on the controls *within* the list box item, not the list box item itself.  The click events would bubble up to the `ListBoxItem` and would allow it to be selected.  I *think* you can do what you want by overriding the style of the `ListBoxItem` in your `ListBox`.  Start with a copy of the list box item style then add a `Setter` to change the `IsHitTestVisible` property.  For example:

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}"></ListBox>
```

And in your page resources (only change from the copy was the `IsHitTestVisible` property):

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Comment: Can we do BINDING in SETTER in WP 8.1? Because i have used the same solution. But its not working

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is as explained by @PeterRitchie. If that's correct, I think there is a simpler way to fix it. Try to bind `IsHitTestVisible` property of `ListBoxItem` using style setter this way :

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```